# Laravel 8 Multiple Auth with two different models return False even when credentials are true

Tags: laravel, authentication

i have created a second model for authenticating as company, i add the guard and provide
but enable to login!

Company class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class Company extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guard = 'company';

    protected $guarded = [];

}
```

Config/Auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'company' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'company',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'company' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Company::class,
    ],
],
```

CompanyLoginController

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Entreprise;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CompanyLoginController extends Controller
{

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    

        if (Auth::guard('company')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ]);
    }
}
```

the $hasher->check() was the one returning false after going deep in te code but for some reason i couldn't find the solution.

Comment: while register make sure you save `Hashed` password

Comment: it's hashed, with the Hash facade, Hash::make()

Comment: try `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: i've tried it before nothing changes

Comment: then use manually

Comment: how to do that manually?

Comment: `protected $guard = 'enrtreprise';` this should be `protected $guard = 'company';`

Comment: yeah it is, just updated it

Comment: setting `$guard` on a model does nothing; there is nothing using that property ... how did you define the password field for this table in the migration?

Comment: $table->string('password')

Answer (score 0):

as you said you builtin function is not working so you can try manual method like this

```php
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $company = Company::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if (!$company) {
        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The email doest not exist.',
        ]);
    }


    if (Hash::check($request->password, $company->password)) {
        auth()->guard('company')->login($company);
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }

    return back()->withErrors([
        'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
    ]);
}
```